# Security measure to implement a password field on rust?

Tags: rust, passwords, command-line-interface, stdin

Are there any security measures that I should implement when I do a password cli field on rust? Will using `readline()` method from the `std::io::Stdin` be enough?
Something like this:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin(); // We get `Stdin` here.
    stdin.read_line(&mut buffer)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Edit: Without using external crates like `rpassword` or using other programming language